# C# - LINQ Select returns a value but the variable is still null

Tags: c#, linq

```
private static readonly List<long> KnownPrimes = new List<long>() { 2, 3, 5, 7};
        
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numDivisors;
    string input = "";
    bool first = true;
    while (!int.TryParse(input, out numDivisors))
    {
        if(!first) Console.WriteLine("You must enter a number with no other characters.");
        Console.WriteLine("Find the least common multiple for numbers 1 through:");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        first = false;
    }

    int index = -1;
    //make sure that there are enough primes in the list
    while (index == -1)
    {
                
        index = KnownPrimes.FindIndex(n => n > numDivisors);
        if(index == -1) AppendNextPrime();
     }
     // prep the list with 0s
     List<int> countPrimes = KnownPrimes.Select(n=>0) as List<int>;
```

When I debug that last line in Rider, it is showing:

```
Enumerable.Select() returned: Count = 5       countPrimes: null
```

From what I have read, LINQ shouldn't be able to return a null, and it doesn't appear to be, but somehow the variable is remaining null. I'm obviously missing something here, can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#111112-the-as-operator) will return null since the result of the Select ist no `List<int>` but an `IEnumerable<int>`. Replace it by `ToList` to make a List out of the IEnumerable:

`List<int> countPrimes = KnownPrimes.Select(n=>0).ToList();`

Comment: Interesting ... I'm surprised that Rider would recommend the "as" operator in a case like this, but thank you. That fixed the problem, and I guess I'll have to be more careful about following IDE suggestions.

Comment: Rider suggests this, as you have declared you expect the vaiable List<int> first, not var. 
Thus, defining the expected return type, makes Rider think you know what you are doing, thus making sure that the return type you are applying, a resulting variable to, is identical to the defined variable. 

The question is, why would define the variable as a different type than your return type?